# datagrid lost connection with DataSource after datatable.copy

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have two datatable

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();      
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
```

then I add data to "dt" datatable and set it as source for datagridview

```
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "One");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Two");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Three");
        dataGridView1.DataSource =dt;
```

then i copy dt to dt1 and clear data in dt

```
        dt1 = dt.Copy();           
        dt.Clear();
```

now after copy back dt1 to dt the datagrid lost the source:

```
dt = dt1.Copy();
```

the datagrid now showing nothing  even though dt had data,but when reassign datagrid to dt again the data show up

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource =dt;
```

My question here why datagrid lost source after copying and is there a way to copy from data table without reassigning datasource

Comment: do you clear `dt1` after `dt = dt1.Copy();` ?

Comment: no ,I don't, thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is because DataTable.Copy does return a *new* instance of DataTable.

So when you do this: "dt = dt1.Copy()" you are actually replacing dt with a new reference.

Your datagrid however still uses the old reference of "dt" (they are completely different objects now, where the "old" one was just cleared by you...hence no data).

Update (after "is there a way" comment): yes there is. MSDN is your friend. Did not know that off the top of my head either. DataTable.Merge does what you want (probably - cause we do not know what you want hehe)

Comment: thanks, I get that now but is there a way to copy data from another table without replacing the reference